# Syncope CSV connector not creating users

Tags: java, identity, apache-syncope

I have been playing with Apache Syncope and tried creating a CSV connector with a resource and a Pull task assigned.

The connector parameters:

```
File mask: \.csv
Key column name: id [override]
Password column name: employeeNum
Column names: id,fn,sn,employeeNum
```

Everything selected for capabilities.

On the resource part I have All propagation actions selected and every propagation set to ALL.

In the provision rules I have:

```
key - employeeNum [remote key]
email - email
password - __PASSWORD__ [password]
username - fn
```

In the pull tasks configuration I have:
    Matching rule - Link
    Unmatching rule - Provision
    Allow create, update, etc.

And when I run the pull task the message is: `Users [created/failures]: 0/0 [updated/failures]: 0/0 [deleted/failures]: 0/0 [no operation/ignored]: 0/0` and no users are created.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to how I understood the concepts of `File mask` and `Source path`.

My issue was that I was putting in the `Source path` the absolute path to the file, not the directory where the file is.

The solution would be something like:

```
Source path: path/to/the/folder
File mask: fileName.csv
```